# How to disable read only mode in MicroStrategy 9.3

Tags: microstrategy

In MicroStrategy 9.3 how do I get out of read only mode?

Research has suggested that it is available under the Schema menu when the project is selected, but I don't see a read only option in the Schema menu.

When viewing settings from Architect the option for disable schema changes is checked and disabled, so I can't uncheck it.

I was able to work around this via a registry hack (Setting HKLM\Software\MicroStrategy readonly = 1), but was hoping for the "right" way to do this. I've been looking through the MicroStrategy website, PDF docs, and blogs to no avail..

Any clues? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out: this product was actually a reseller packaged version of MicroStrategy called Trapeze Viewpoint. Trapeze had disabled the registry setting to prevent folks from accidentally editing the out of box schema / projects. In this case the docs were all correct, and the registry hack makes the read only options visible in the menu, and allowed me to edit my project.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Read only mode will visible only when you will be logged inside a "Project". It will not be visible if you have clicked only on "Project Source".

Once you are logged in a project, You can enable Read-Only mode from Administration -> Locking -> LockProject  too.
In the same way if you want to unlock go to Administration -> Locking -> Unlock Project.

Hope you will find it helpful!!

**Thanks,**